# Why is python process with unbuffered output scrambled using xargs --max-procs?

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, buffered

I'm executing multiple python processes like such:

```
find /path/to/logfiles/*.gz | xargs -n1 -P4 python logparser.py
```

and the output is occasionally scrambled.

The output stream is unbuffered and the size of the the write is smaller 
than the default system (osx 10.8.2, python 2.7.2) defined PIPE_BUF of 512 bytes, so i believe the writes should be atomic, but output is occasionally scrambled.  I must be missing something and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

A simplified skeleton of the script is:

```
import argparse
import csv
import gzip


class class UnbufferedWriter(object):
    """Unbuffered Writer from 
       http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-November/026645.html

    """

    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def write(self, data):
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)


def parse_records(infile):
    if infile.name.endswith('.gz'):
        lines = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=infile)
    else:
        lines = infile

    for line in lines:
        # match lines with regex and filter out on some conditions.
        yield line_as_dict

def main(infile, outfile):
    fields = ['remote_addr', 'time', 'request_time', 'request', 'status']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for record in parse_records(infile):
        row_as_dict = dict(
            remote_addr=record.get('remote_addr', ''),
            time=record.get('time', ''),
            request_time=record.get('request_time', ''),
            request=record.get('request', ''),
            status=record.get('status', '')
        )
        writer.writerow(row_as_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
    parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w', 0), default=sys.stdout)

    pargs = parser.parse_args()
    pargs.outfile = UnbufferedWriter(pargs.outfile)

    main(pargs.infile, pargs.outfile)
```

Comment: Do you still get scrambled output when you run it serially (without -P4)?  By scrambled do you mean that it is the correct output, only mixed up or is it all nonsense?

Comment: No, when run serially it is correct.  By scrambled I mean that very few lines (~.25%) are truncated before end of line or portions of multiple lines are merged to a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). By default, the output is buffered until the instance has completed running:

> When running jobs that output data, you often do not want the output
>   of multiple jobs to run together. GNU parallel defaults to grouping
>   the output of each job, so the output is printed when the job
>   finishes. If you want the output to be printed while the job is
>   running you can use -u.

I believe the best way to run your script is vai:

```
find /path/to/logfiles/*.gz | parallel python logparser.py
```

or

```
parallel python logparser.py ::: /path/to/logfiles/*.gz
```

You can specify the number of processes to run using the `-j` flag, i.e., `-j4`.

The nice thing about Parallel is that is supports cartesian products of input arguments. For example, if you had some additional arguments that you wanted to iterate through for each file, you can use:

```
parallel python logparser.py ::: /path/to/logfiles/*.gz ::: 1 2 3
```

This will result in running the following across multiple processes:

```
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/A.gz 1
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/A.gz 2
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/A.gz 3
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/B.gz 1
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/B.gz 2
python logparser.py /path/to/logfiles/B.gz 3
...
```

Good luck!

Comment: I would like to focus on what i might be doing wrong, rather than changing tools.  Additionally, parallel is not installed by default on OSX, nor on the SL6 box this will run on in production.  Using the --max-procs flag works when using a perl script that performs similar functionality.

Comment: But this _is_ what you're doing wrong. You're not buffering your output, which means that it gets written mixed up to the terminal, because the processes write to the terminal in undetermined order (as they're running in parallel).

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. xargs has a race condition that causes mixed output, and it is sheer luck that your perl script is not hit by this. See the race condition and a perl script that is affected by it on http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_xargs_and_gnu_parallel If you are allowed to run a perl script, then you are also allowed to run GNU Parallel as that is a single perl script. See 'Minimal installation' in: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

Comment: okay, i'll try to get parallel incorporated, but i'm a little confused.  the writes are atomic, so what is the xargs race condition, what is it doing with stdout?  Also, the following seems to work:  `find /path/to/logfiles/*.gz | xargs -n1 -P4 python logparser.py | cat`.  So why would writing to the pipe work, but not the terminal?

Comment: The terminal and a pipe buffers differently. To see the xargs race condition please run the (2nd) example on: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_xargs_and_gnu_parallel